# javascript pass screen width to function

Tags: javascript

I have implemented an infinite scroll and I need to modify the width of all elements to adjust to the display width.

the code is

```
 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv');
 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
       elements[i].style.width = (screen.width / 2);
 }
```

and does not work (does not change the width of the div)

but

```
 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv');
 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
       elements[i].style.width = "10px";
 }
```

works

and alert(screen.width) returns correctly the screen's width.

can someone help me ?

Comment: `Element.style.Width` expects a value with units... So it should be `= (screen.width /2) +  "px"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `px` - the unit is expected

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.myDiv')
  .forEach(div => div.style.width = `${(screen.width / 2)}px`)
```

```css
.myDiv { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="myDiv" style="width:100px">Hello</div>
<div class="myDiv" style="width:200px">Hello</div>
<div class="myDiv" style="width:300px">Hello</div>
<div class="myDiv" style="width:400px">Hello</div>
<div class="myDiv" style="width:500px">Hello</div>
<div class="myDiv" style="width:600px">Hello</div>
```